# Problem with double field type in postgis database

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, postgis-2.0

I have connection to PostGIS spatial database through ArcSDE, and all double type numeric fields are cutting numbers after comma. Does anyone know how can I fix this problem?

Comment: What datatype are you using? What does an 'sdetable -o describe' report?

Comment: I create field, type-double. When you do that in local gdb database on my computer it's working normal, when i do that on Post gis database it's cutting  numbers after comma. If you type 300.123456 it's only  300.

Comment: What does 'sdetable -o describe' report?

Comment: I am not sure what is that, but when i check that field with pg admin it s type numeric ( Lenght 18, precision 8)

Comment: Sorry, Lenght 38 :)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using commas as decimal separators?  If you are do PostGIS and ArcSDE both handle using commas for decimal separators in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

you should use type NUMERIC, that may fix things at least in postgresql: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-numeric.html, or you can try "periods" (.) instead of "commas" (,).

But I think this problem goes deeper into the format itself. This is in case you're dealing with GDB somewhere in your process, take a look at these links:

1. http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2009/04/esri-formats-back-to-future.html
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/postgis-users/j22Ho59t6KI/1gYjpwF39VUJ

in that case, this may help you out:

- [Migrating geodatabase data into PostGIS without Esri apps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14432/how-to-migrate-gdb-data-into-postgis-without-esri-apps)

Comment: Field are numeric already, but in the field i can't see numbers after comma, for example if i type 200,123456 and save changes in table  will be only 200, but mandatory fields (shape area) are good. So i'm very confused.

Comment: please see my update above